# Evaluation of custom SVM on training set

Tags: machine-learning, svm, supervised-learning

I am trying to build an SVM using libraries from python like cvxopt et al.

I am generating random 2D points and adding labels (1/-1)to them. Also, using this prediction function to evaluate points, 
 $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n z_iy_iK(x_i,x)$.

So, I decided to try it on the same training set (from which I derived Lagrange mults. and their corresponding support vectors), expecting that I would get back the same label sequence (1/-1). However, although it would get some of them correct, it gave me many misclassifications sometimes it looks even random , but most of the time accuracy looks like 50-65% on the same training set. Is this normal? Shouldn't it be like 100%? I am talking about like 20-25 2-D points, generated by random normal dist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

- If you're applying some regularization $C$, you're constricting the
  model flexibility so it's not always going to be the case that the
  SVM will perform well on training data.
- It sounds as if you're applying labels randomly to the data
  (suggested by 50% accuracy), regardless of $(x,y)$ coordinates, it
  shouldn't be surprising that the SVM will generally have difficulty
  predicting points using $(x,y)$ data, since there's no information
  for the model to learn from.
- 25 points is a very small amount of data to use for any
  classification task.
- Your prediction function omits an intercept term. Most SVM software estimates a parameter $b$ which is used in the prediction equation in this manner: $$
  \hat{y}=b+\sum^n_{i=1}z_iy_iK(x_i,x)
  $$ where $\hat{y}$ is the signed distance from the decision boundary.
- Using accuracy is the wrong metric to assess model performance if the costs of misclassficiation are not identical, since
  it assumes the signum function is the correct decision boundary,
  which does not respect mis-classification utilities.
- You don't specify what kernel function you're using, but not all
  kernel functions are equally well-suited to some specific class.
- To check if your optimizer is working correctly, see if your output matches that of some other SVM estimation function.

Comment: Thanks for your long answer. I have used many different kernels, looks like the old typical linear works better, but still i don't see any significant difference to be honest, maybe it is due to i used small amount of points. Also, what do you mean that my function omits an intercept term. Which one is it?

Comment: @Modium The small number of points is not trivial. Due to digitization, the smallest nonzero difference in alternative SVMs' accuracy is $1/25=0.04$, which is the difference of correctly classifying one example. You need more much more data to say anything meaningful about the difference between kernels.